# Difference between TXT file and CSV file - DBA

Tags: sql-server, csv, sharepoint, txt

I upload a file to my database through a process that takes my TXT file with 100000 rows to my information system.

My question is why is better to use a TXT file and not a CSV file?

What is the difference?

The database is an SQL Server and the information system is SharePoint.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Who says it is better?

Comment: A csv file is a a particular Text file with comma (,) as separator.

Comment: A CSV file *is* a text file. there are no differences. CSV is a general term and sometimes it can just refer to delimited data eg usually by comma but also tab, pipe, or whatever.

Comment: A CSV file is a TEXT file where columns are separated from each other with a comma. It is not inherently superior to text files using other delimiters (like tab characters), or those with fixed column positions. Each have pros and cons, and ways to address them.   Unfortunately some tools (like EXCEL) refer to tab delimited text files as TXT extension. And if you are referring to those (ie comparing 'Tab delimited' text  files (.TXT) to 'Comma Separated Value' text files (.CSV), the TXT has one advantage that it is less likely to have the delimiter as part of the actual data than the comma.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are basically text files only. The only thing is, we are telling explicitly that the values are separated by comma. Instead of CSV, if you use TSV, we are telling explicitly that the values are separated by tab.

when you load the data, you will be specifying the format file accordingly. So, in other words TSV or CSV no difference in the background. Both are text files i.e., TXT Files.

Say, you are having two fields in your file. You can still keep it as TXT file.

If you have Comma separated values(CSV), your format file will look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="40" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="40" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Column1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Column2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

If you have Tab separated values(TSV), your format file look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="40" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="40" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Column1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Column2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

- So, CSV is basically TXT file with values separated by commas.
- TSV is basically TXT file with values separated by tabs.